# Change default finder select statement in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-3.1

I'd like to change the default statement that ActiveRecord uses to query a model's table.  By default, it queries a table "cables" for example by...

```
this_cable = Cable.first
```

results in

```
SELECT "cables".* FROM "cables" LIMIT 1
```

I would like to find a way for it to wind up with

```
SELECT *,askml(wkb_geometry) as kml FROM "cables" LIMIT 1
```

This way i can call a database function and have that behave like a field on the object.

```
this_cable.kml
=> "<LineString><coordinates>-73.976879999999994,40.674999999999997 -73.977029999999999,40.674779999999998 -73.977170000000001,40.674770000000002 -73.97775,40.67501</coordinates></LineString>"
```

This can be accomplished by adding a scope

```
scope :with_kml, "*,askml(wkb_geometry) as kml"
```

But I figure that's kind of messy.  I would like this "kml" column to always be there, without having to call the "with_kml" scope.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [default_scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class) for this, or do you actually want this to be present on all your models?

Something like this might solve your problem:

```
default_scope select("*, askml(wkb_geometry) as kml")
```

You might want to change that to `cables.*` for it to work properly with joins and such, though.